# Why can the semantic closure over a structure have no model

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I do not understand why the following should hold in first-order logic. Can someone please help me with an initiative (or proof-based) explanation?

Suppose you have a $\Sigma$-structure, and let $Fm(\Sigma)$ be the set of all formulas over this $\Sigma$-structure (given by defintion 1.4, page 3 [here](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.vandenberg3/Onderwijs/Model%20Theory%202017/syllabus_model_theory.pdf)). Let $X^{\vDash} = \{\phi : X \vDash \phi\}$ Then,

1- If $X^{\vDash} = Fm(\Sigma)$, then Mod$(X) = \emptyset$.

2- If $X$ is a set of propositions (formulas with no free variables) and Mod$(X) = \emptyset$, then $X^{\vDash} = Fm(\Sigma)$

Comment: **All** formulas, without further details, means also $\phi$ as well as $\lnot \phi$.

Comment: What does $Mod(X)$ mean?

Comment: Perhaps Mod(X) is the set (or class) of all models. Note that "the class of all models is empty" would mean the there is no model, whereas (as in the title) having an empty model to me seems to imply that the empty set happens to be a model. The question does not seem to be stated unambiguously.

Comment: @Mirko $Mod(X)$ is standard notation for the set of all models of $X$. Note that if $X\subseteq Y$ then $Mod(X)\supseteq Mod(Y)$: more sentences = more rules = fewer structures satisfying them all.

Answer (score 2):

1. You now that there is at least an atomic formula, $\phi$, in $Fm(\Sigma)$, therefore $\lnot \phi \in Fm(\Sigma)$, in other words $\phi, \lnot \phi \in X$, what does this tell you about the models of X?
2. The harder direction is $Fm(\Sigma) \subseteq X$. Given $\phi \in Fm(\Sigma)$, for all  models $M$, $M \nvDash X$ and so it holds $M \vDash X \implies M \vDash \phi$, wich means $\phi \in X^\vDash$.

Comment: I don't understand how you deduced "....and so it holds $M \vDash X \implies M \vDash \phi$"

Comment: if $a$ is not true then $a \implies b$ is true

Comment: Aha I see thank a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!